# Is there any way to call onActivityResult() method to return data from Activity in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have a `Fragment` containing a `RecyclerView`. I am starting an Intent to a new `Activity` from this `Fragment`. Now I want to add some new data in DB from this `Activity` and update my `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` when the `Activity` is finished. 
I know that `onActivityResult()` method will work in `Activity` only. Is there any way to achieve this in `Fragment`?

Comment: Yes in fragment you can also achieve.

Comment: Do you know `EventBus` in Android ? Go with that

Comment: @MD Yes I know _EventBus_

Comment: `I know that onActivityResult() method will work in Activity only.` you are wrong about this. `onActivityResult` works just file in fragment.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you can get that callback in fragment also.. just `startActivityForResult` from fragment. and override `onActivityResult()` in both activity and fragment. just dont use super in activity so that it will redirect you to your fragment method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override `onActivityResult` a handler method in fragment, it will automatically get called from activity. In latest implementation of SDK it automatically forwards to fragment [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))